# Why I get different network traffic values from dom0 and from domU?

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, xen

I'm using Xen 4.0.1 with Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 (standard packages on a Debian Squeeze system).

From [Xen Networking](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#Virtual_Ethernet_interfaces):

> For each new domU, Xen creates a new pair of "connected virtual ethernet
> interfaces", with one end in domU and the other in dom0. For linux domU's,
> the device name it sees is named eth0. The other end of that virtual
> ethernet interface pair exists within dom0 as interface vif<id#>.0
>
> Think of them as two ethernet interfaces connected by an internal crossover
> ethernet cable.

My understanding of this *internal crossover* thing is that networking statistics should be the same no matter if you measure it in the dom0 (*vifN.N* interface) or in the domU (*eth0*  interface). RX/TX values should be the same, just inverted.

Nevertheless I'm getting **~20% larger** values when traffic is measured in dom0. My question is **why the values are (that) different**?

Starting the guest domain:

```
root@dev1:/etc/xen# xm create node2050.cfg
Using config file "./node2050.cfg".
Started domain node2050 (id=35)

root@dev1:/etc/xen# xm list node2050
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
node2050                                    35   256     1     -b----      2.5

root@dev1:/etc/xen# ip address show vif35.0
70: vif35.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 32
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In domU:

```
node2050:~# ip address show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:44:2e:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.yy.zz.50/24 brd xx.yy.zz.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe44:2e5a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Just after starting `node2050`:

In dom0.

```
root@dev1:~# while true; do date; cat /sys/class/net/vif35.0/statistics/{r,t}x_bytes; sleep 1; done
...
Thu Jan 19 13:18:00 EST 2012
4826
466049
Thu Jan 19 13:18:01 EST 2012
4826
466580
Thu Jan 19 13:18:02 EST 2012
4826
467427
Thu Jan 19 13:18:03 EST 2012
4826
467910
Thu Jan 19 13:18:04 EST 2012
4826
468769
Thu Jan 19 13:18:05 EST 2012
4826
469764
```

in domU:

```
root@node2050:~# while true; do date; cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/{r,t}x_bytes; sleep 1; done
 ...
Thu Jan 19 13:18:00 EST 2012
395229
5792
Thu Jan 19 13:18:01 EST 2012
395961
5792
Thu Jan 19 13:18:02 EST 2012
396617
5792
Thu Jan 19 13:18:03 EST 2012
397304
5792
Thu Jan 19 13:18:04 EST 2012
397735
5792
Thu Jan 19 13:18:05 EST 2012
398620
5792
```

The config:

```
root@dev1:/etc/xen# cat node2050.cfg 
kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64'
ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64'
vcpus       = '1'
memory      = '256'
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
              'phy:/dev/vg0/node2050-disk,xvda2,w',
              'phy:/dev/vg0/node2050-swap,xvda1,w',
              ]
name        = 'node2050'
vif         = [ 'ip=xx.yy.zz.50,mac=00:16:3E:44:2E:5A' ]
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
extra       = 'console=hvc0 xencons=hvc0'
```

Comment: This is a good question. I think you should try the Xen mailing list and then get back to us with your results.

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses:
    1. Traffic that came in before the DomU xennet was ready to receive. 20℅ is pretty much, though. Do you boot often and have low normal traffic?
    2. Broadcast/Multicast Traffic not targeted to the DomU? Is there perhaps an incoming firewall on the DomU?